# SQL query regarding nested query topic

Tags: mysql

Query that displays all "Father (Husband)" names in alphabetical order from `Guardian` table with total number of their "Wives" (use nested query to find count of wives).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwObQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your questions is hard to understand. Please try to ask more precise and specific so that others can help you more easily. So also these recommendations: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join and group by

```
 select a.guardianName as husband_name, count(*) as count_of_wives
 from my_table a 
 left join my_table b  on b.husband_id = a.guardianId
 where a.husband_id is null 
 group by a.guardianName
```